# Como edentar uma resposta json usando o Gson

Tags: java, gson

Primeiramente concordo que a pergunta ficou meio estranha, mas não consigo escrever de outra forma minha dúvida. Ao fim da explicação do problema se alguém quiser sugerir um melhor título que expresse melhor o problema ficarei agradecido.

Vamos lá. Hoje tenho um `map` com valores da seguinte forma:

```
HashMap<String, Pessoa> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("max", pessoa1);
map.put("min", pessoa2);
```

Aplico a biblioteca `Gson` e recebo o seguinte json:

```
{
    "min": {
        "name": "Fulano",
        "age": 10,
    },
    "max": {
        "name": "Siclano",
        "age": 13
    }
}
```

Mas o que eu preciso é: (Reparem nos colchetes `[]`):

```
{
    "min": [
        "name": "Fulano",
        "age": 10,
    ],
    "max": [
        "name": "Siclano",
        "age": 13
    ]
}
```

O que eu preciso fazer para que o `json` venha com os colchetes?

Vi essa pergunta no [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750966/using-gson-how-to-add-variable-name-as-top-level-parameter-for-json-of-a-rest-ca). Tem **relação** com o meu problema.

Comment: O formato que você precisa não é um formato JSON válido. Vc está consumindo alguma API que requere este formato?

Comment: `[]` geralmente são usados para representar coleções. Você já tentou um `Map<String, List<Pessoa>>`, `Map<String, Pessoa[]>` ou `Map<String, List<Map<String, Serializable>>>`?. Exemplo de adição: `map.put("max", Collections.singleton(mapaPessoa1)`. Não sei exatamente como você está fazendo o *marshalling* mas uma dessas opções deve chegar perto do que você deseja.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly vou tentar suas alternativas

Comment: Reforço a justificativa do @LeonardoLima . A estrutura que você quer não representa um formato JSON. O mais próximo que dá pra chegar disso é "min": [{"name": "fulano", "age": 10}].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perceba um detalhe, seu Map referencia Pessoa, logo, a representação do seu JSON tratará cada item como um item independente. O fato de ser Map força isso, pois se trata de um objeto altamente dinâmico.

Outro detalhe é que você necessita da representação de um Array [ ], porém está sendo forçado a representação de um objeto { }, pois quando realiza o put no Map, é realizada a inclusão de um novo objeto.

Alternativa 1: Você pode fazer uma nova análise na estrutura que você precisa, não parece que faz muito sentido a forma com que você está utilizando.

Alternativa 2: Você substitui os atributos de Pessoa para uma List.

Alternativa 3: Você pode utilizar o http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/, como parâmetro de modelagem.

Grande abraço e boa sorte.

Comment: Vou tentar suas alternativas. Origado